# Granting windows admin privileges

Tags: windows

When executing a program on windows you can request that you get admin access and, I believe, everything that is done by that program is run as though by an admin. (Correct me if I am wrong here.)

Now, Let's say I have Program A, B and C. Program A is launched and given admin privileges. A then calls B, which calls C, and then C performs an operation that needs admin privileges. My question is, does C have admin privileges and uses them to execute that task? If it doesn't is a program that is given admin privileges (Program A in this case) able to pass its admin privileges to those it calls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal call to [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) will create a new child process using the same token (user account and its groups and privileges) as the parent process and this token will also be used by its grandchildren if the child process also uses `CreateProcess`.

Other methods (`ShellExecute`) that **might** start a new process can end up reusing a existing process ([DDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Data_Exchange) etc.) or start the new process using indirect methods (COM activation).